# Case to use java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of dto and a list of bean.

I remove an element in the list of beans if it doesn't exist in the list of dto.

```
public void convertToBeans(CarsDto dto, Cars bean){
    List<CarsDto> carsDto = dto.getCars();
    List<Cars> cars = bean.getCars();

    for (SatcomChannels satcomChannel : satcomChannels) {

    if(satcomChannelsDto.stream().anyMatch(b -> b.getId()==satcomChannel.getId())){
        //do nothing here
    }else{
        //remove element
    }
}
```

is it a more efficient way to change this code instead of have if condition who do nothing

noneMatch seem to do the job

Comment: There's not enough context. What is `containsId()`? What is `removeCars()`?

Comment: @Eugene. My mistake. Deleted.

Comment: Another question is if `bean.getCars()` is returning a new List or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `filter`. Take a look:

```
List<String> bean = new ArrayList<>();
bean.add("1");
bean.add("2");
bean.add("3");
bean.add("4");
bean.add("5");
List<String> dto = new ArrayList<>();
dto.add("1");
dto.add("2");

List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

bean.forEach(obj -> {
    if (!dto.contains(obj)) {
        toRemove.add(obj);
    }
});

bean.removeAll(toRemove);

System.out.println(bean);
```

It works by iterating on the bean list and adding on toRemove list those which are not present in dto list. And remove all in bean list using toRemove list.

This code will output `[1, 2]` which are the items in both lists.

Comment: a little different... search to remove element in beans who don't exist in dto

Comment: by removing you mean executing some method or simply removing from array?

Comment: i mean from array

Comment: See my updated answer if it fits